# Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in

Tags: php

I am receiving the following error: Fatal error:

Call to a member function get() on a non-object in

I created a public function get(), to retrieve sql data that has been queried.

I am currently working on the validation stage and I incorporated the get function to check the database to see if the account email is already registered.

I created the following rules via an array:

```
$validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
                                                'fName' => array(
                                                  'required' => true,
                                                  'min' => 2,
                                                  'max' => 20),

                                                'lName' => array(
                                                  'required' => true,
                                                  'min' => 2,
                                                  'max' => 20),

                                                'regEmail' => array(
                                                  'required' => true,
                                                  'min' => 2,
                                                  'max' => 50,
                                                  'unique' => 'customers'),

                                                'regEmailCon' => array(
                                                  'required' => true,
                                                  'min' => 2,
                                                  'max' => 50,
                                                  'matches' => 'regEmail'),

                                                'regPword' => array(
                                                  'required' => true,
                                                  'min' => 6,
                                                  'max' => 12),

                                                'regPwordCon' => array(
                                                  'required' => true,
                                                  'matches' => 'regPword'),
                                                ));
```

here is the code used to perform the validation:

```
    public function check($source, $items = array()){
    foreach($items as $item => $rules ){
        foreach ($rules as $rule => $rule_value){

            $value = trim($source[$item]);
            $item = escape($item);

            if($rule === 'required' && empty($value)){
                $this->addError("{$item} is required");
            }elseif (!empty($value)){
                switch ($rule){
                    case 'min':
                        if(strlen($value) < $rule_value){
                            $this->addError("{$item} must be a minimum of {$rule_value} characters.");
                        }
                    break;
                    case'max':
                        if(strlen($value) > $rule_value){
                            $this->addError("{$item} must be a maximum of {$rule_value} characters.");
                        }
                    break;
                    case 'matches':
                        if ($value != $source[$rule_value]){
                            $this->addError("{$rule_value} must match {$item}");
                        }

                    break;
                    case'unique':
                        $check = $this->_db->get($rule_value, array("$item", '=', "$value"));
                        if ($check->count()){
                            $this->addError("{$item} already exists.");
                        }
                    break;


                }
            }
        }
    }
```

All cases work until I get to the get() Function. I am not sure what the issue is. Any suggestions?

Alibi, My appologies,

here is what I did at the begining of the class:

```
class Validation{
private $_passed = false,
        $_errors= array(),
        $_db = null;

public function _construct(){
    $this->_db = DB::getInstance();
}/*end _construct*/
```

by adding the private variable _db, I hoped to store the DB::getInstance() function from the singleton pattern.

Thanks a Million

Comment: what does $this->_db refer to? Something within scope of this function?

Comment: The singleton pattern is not good practice. Instead, create a new database object and pass it in to the constructor. This good practice is called Dependency Injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means that `$this->_db` is not an object that has a method called `get`. In order for your code to work, you need something like this to exist:

In the class that has the function `check`:

```
public function __construct($_db) {
  //this is how `check` will get access to a `db` object as a property ("this->$_db")
  $this->$_db = $_db;
}
```

When you instantiate that class:

```
$_db = new db(); //this has a method "get"
//pass the $_db object to the class
$myClass = new MyClass($_db);
```

and the `db` class:

```
class db {
  //this is where the db object is given a method "get"
  public function get() {

  }
}
```